# Api are changing based on account(email id)

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can any one help me to get solution for the api changing based on the email id(account details ) 
ex:
/api/getRooms/test@gmail.com
(last name is changing) for other accounts .

Comment: Hi veena! Do you want to set dynamic api in jmeter??? Kindly elaborate your question

Comment: Hi Veena,  i think this may be a help for you. https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/23/jmeter-rest-api-testing/

Comment: Yes api's are changing based on the user id (email id) while performing for multiple accounts with different user id

Answer (score 0):

Put all the email ids in the csv with header (Header Name:- Email). 
Then, use "CSV Data Set Config" to provide them as inputs to your request. Pass the header as variable to the api like /api/getRooms/${Email}.

[image]

Comment: While running the api (for dynamic value)getting response as                                                              Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

Comment: Mostly this happens when there is no proper correlation done for the dynamic values like sessionid, view state, tokens. First, try to rerun the recorded api call and make it success by doing coorelation. Also, use Authorization Manager, if not used (https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

Comment: Run of Post api getting response as 404(not found)  error i tried with csv config

Comment: It is giving 404 without csv also then problem is that page/resources doesnot exist. But, if it is working without csv then with csv it should also work until the data you have created exist. It means the email account created are valid and updated properly.

Comment: But getting data in the debug sampler, its working for GET method,

Comment: If I understand it correctly, data from csv is fetched and replaced in the api but it is giving 404. Try to hit the api with the URL created manually. Also, check if there is some extra space introduced somewhere.

Comment: <html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You need to hit the api which is giving 404 directly and check if it is the same issue. Else you can post a new issue with more details so that people can check further..Attach plan, log and response. Also, if your original question is solve,kindly accept it as an answer and vote to help others.